# Why can't dart-sass read the directory where output file should be created?

Tags: css, sass

I am having trouble getting dart-sass to watch an SCSS file for changes and then generate a CSS file.  My input file is in my project's static directory:

```
/srv/https/html/repo/static/scss/styles.scss
```

I want the output file to be created and written here:

```
/var/www/html/styles.css
```

I'm using the latest version of dart-sass for Linux and running this command from the repos directory:

```
sass --watch static/scss:/var/www/html
```

The command produces this error:

```
Error reading ../../../../var/www/html: Creation failed.
```

If I add the full path to the input file and the relative path to the output file like the following, I get the same error:

```
sass --watch /srv/https/html/repo/static/scss:../../../../var/www/html
```

Now I should add that the destination directory `/var/www/html` is cross-mounted via NFS.  At first I thought it was a permissions problem because the directory had permissions `755` as did the existing styles.css file which I had created before using Sass.  But I get the error even if I change the permissions on the parent directory and CSS file to `777`.  Does dart-sass not work with NFS file systems or do I need to run the command a different way?  I should add that if I just run the sass command with `--watch` and specify the paths to the input and output files, sass compiles without an error.